# Highlight table row if cell duplicate

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have the following table:

```
Checkbox (ID)  |  Training Course Code  |  Training Course Name  |  ....
   [ ]         |  DE00155115-1          |  H&S Exec 1            |  ....
   [ ]         |  DE00155115-1          |  H&S Exec 1            |  ....
   [ ]         |  DE00074454-2          |  H&S Exec 2            |  ....
```

Each course runs more than once but can only be selected once hence the multiple IDs per course code.

What I want to do is be able to disable / highlight the duplicate rows once one has been selected.

In the above example if the first row was selected, the second would disable and vice versa. If the third row was selected nothing would happen.

I have attempted several functions using jQuery but not really sure where to start and build from.

Comment: Having more than one id with the same name is invalid html, I suggest you use classes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a long, and slightly involved, option:

```
$('table')
    .on('click','input:checkbox',
        function(){
            var that = $(this),
                thatRow = that.closest('tr'),
                id = that.parent().next('td').text();

            if (that.is(':checked')){
                that
                    .closest('tbody')
                    .find('tr td:nth-child(2)')
                    .each(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).text() == id){
                                $(this)
                                    .closest('tr')
                                    .not(thatRow)
                                    .addClass('disabled')
                                    .find('input:checkbox')
                                    .prop('disabled',true);
                            }
                        });
            }
            else {
                that
                    .closest('tbody')
                    .find('tr td:nth-child(2)')
                    .each(
                        function(){
                            if ($(this).text() == id){
                                $(this)
                                    .closest('tr')
                                    .not(thatRow)
                                    .removeClass('disabled')
                                    .find('input:checkbox')
                                    .prop('disabled',false);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tTwDF/1/).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`:nth-child()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Very detailed example with the references thank you! For future reference, would it be possible to disable rows across 2 tables on the same page? An example being if the course dates were broken into monthly blocks, could you disable a row in all separate tables?

Comment: Absolutely, you'd just need some way of selecting both (or all) tables is all.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. Do you have an example or any pointers where to start reading? Thanks again :)

Comment: Replace `that.closest('tbody').find('tr td:nth-child(2)')` with `$('table').find('tbody tr td:nth-child(2)')`: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tTwDF/2/).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, then all you need to implement a click handler for the checkbox like below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/NgQLw/2/)

```
$('#courses > tbody > tr > td > .selectCourse').on('click', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
    var selCourseCode = $tr.find('td:eq(1)').html();
    var isChecked = this.checked;
    if (isChecked) {
        $tr.addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $tr.removeClass('highlight');
    }

    $.each ($tr.siblings(), function () {
        var courseCode = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();
        if (courseCode == selCourseCode) {
            if (isChecked) {
                $(this).find('.selectCourse').prop('disabled', true);
                $(this).addClass('disable');
            } else {
                $(this).find('.selectCourse').removeProp('disabled');
                $(this).removeClass('disable');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.highlight { background-color: #386C98; }
.disable { background-color: #386C98; color: grey; }
```

Comment: It would appear you beat me to it, but not by much. Very similar approach.

Comment: Very useful looking at the different approaches, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample jQuery function that should work in older versions of IE (8/7/6):

http://jsfiddle.net/lazerblade01/d2QtL/9/

Answer (score 0):

when you generate the table, add an atribute to html cell like

```
 <td data-course-name="math">math</td>
```

when using jquery try

```
 $('td[data-course-name=' + name of the course + ']').css( apply css here)
```

It's simple

Comment: Unfortunately, this would require the use of HTML5, so if someone comes to this page with IE 8/7/6, this won't work.